# Static Method and Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, static-methods

I know similar questions have already been asked here, but I have not found answers there that would satisfy me.

There is a STATIC searchFile method to search for a given file in a given directory. Its prototype looks like this:

```
boolean searchFile(File root, String fileName);
```

I need to scan the entire drive looking for a file.
I decided to entrust this business to several threads for faster search, but I ran into a problem. Because the method is static, it would be incorrect to use this method to perform a given task across multiple threads like this:

```
class SearchTask implements Runnable {
    private File root;
    private String fileName;

    SearchTask(File root, String fileName) { this(root, fileName); }

    public void run() {
        // calling the static method searchFile
        Something.searchFile(root, fileName);
    }
}
```

What to do in such a situation?

Comment: Why do you think it would be incorrect to do this? It should be ok if all threads start from a different root.

Comment: @BurakSerdar: As the OP has currently written it, this is unlikely to work, as there's no coordination of any kind between threads.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, splitting your search like this is unlikely to obtain a performance benefit, especially on a spindle drive where it will probably make things worse due to thrashing of the drive heads.

Comment: What @RobertHarvey said. Multithreading is beneficial for (some) CPU-bound tasks. The limiting factor here isn't your CPU, it's disk I/O. As for your general question, it sounds like you're asking about *reentrancy*. You can search and read about what makes a method reentrant. (And reentrancy is just one thing that can make a method thread-safe. There are others.)